# Mapbox iOS's flyToCamera keeps on going back to initial location unless user moves around map first

Tags: ios, mapbox, mapbox-gl

flyToCamera goes to the new camera location and then goes back to the previous camera location.

If the user moves the map (using drag gesture), even if a little bit, the flyToCamera function starts working.

This is my code:

```
 - (void) goToSomeCity {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D  city = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(34.0522,-118.2437);
    MGLMapCamera *originCamera = [MGLMapCamera cameraLookingAtCenterCoordinate:city fromEyeCoordinate:self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate eyeAltitude:5000];
    [self.mapView flyToCamera:originCamera completionHandler:^{
        // Optionally do something
    }];
}
```

The function is called by a button:

```
- (IBAction)userPressedGoToCity {
    [self goToSomeCity];
}
```

If the user presses the button when the app starts or without moving around first (dragging the map to change the center of the map), then the function will go to the new camera and then move back to the initial location. But when the user does drag to move around the map, even if a little bit, the function works.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a [user tracking mode](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.7.6/Enums/MGLUserTrackingMode.html) enabled, which will move the map to follow the location of the user (and disable when the user moves the map themselves).